# Custom the color of an youtube player embed

Tags: javascript, css, api, youtube, youtube-api

For some projets I want to set the color of the progress bar or the play button of a youtube player.

I know we can set to white with adding on the src "?color=white" ( red is by default ).

But I want something more like "The Huffinton Post" ( french edition ) video embed :

https://www.huffingtonpost.fr/entry/en-australie-cette-tempete-de-sable-a-transforme-le-jour-en-nuit_fr_5cd302f0e4b07ce6ef795848

But I didn't find it in the source code. 
I have try to use JS and Jquery to add a css file ( to change the rules colors ) in to the iframe, without sucess ...

How I should to do that ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

It's a YouTube back end feature which is special for huffingtonpost.fr. Here's why:

1. Open https://www.huffingtonpost.fr/robots.txt (we want a page where there is no CSS and JavaScript)
2. Open DevTools and choose the Elements tab
3. Change the contents of the `<body>` to the following:

   ```
   <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" allowfullscreen="allowFullScreen" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Hv_pklVVrQI" width="854" height="480" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
   ```
4. You will see the green button and controls background

On every other domain this will show the normal "theme".

---

Other websites:

- https://ze.tt/endometriose-betroffene-erzaehlen-wie-sie-mit-der-chronischen-erkrankung-umgehen/
- https://www.france24.com/en/20200226-india-s-modi-appeals-for-peace-and-brotherhood-after-delhi-riots

---

Only works on videos uploaded by a certain channel. Example:
https://ze.tt/oscarssomale-natalie-portman-feiert-alle-frauen-die-nicht-nominiert-wurden/